# Picasso out of memory error - Android Image Loading in ListView with custom adapter

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, adapter, picasso

So now I included `picasso` and `sonce` then I regularly get out of memory `errors` every time I want to do anything. could this be because of `picasso` caching the images? I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and how to solve... any experiences with that?

EDIT: Solution was pretty simple. had to change my custom `adapters` as suggested by `picasso` to receive images url and load it directly into the `imageview` instead of using the detour of saving as `bitmap`. overlooked the hint, don't know why.
Here's the adapter:

```
public class ImageTextListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;

public ImageTextListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txt;
    TextView id;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_friends, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id_friends);
        holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_friends_textview);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friends_image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txt.setText(rowItem.getText());
    String url = getItem(position).getUrl();

    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.id.setText(rowItem.getId());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I have a `listview` where I load the name from every user from `json` (via `asynctask`) in a `ListView`.
Additionally the user image has to be loaded from server, too. this happens via a second `ajax` request. as I get the `json` with the url for the saved image to get the image then from server, for each image a request is fired via `asynctask`. this makes the load of the `listview` last very long so other activities stay in queue until this task is finished. 
I found out how to save images in memory cache. but that does not solve the problem as the images are only saved when I put the app in background.

the `listview` contains a `custom adapter` called RowItem which contains an `imageview` and two `listviews`.

any suggestions? I am working on this for about 1 day and a half now...

thank you!

heres my Async task for loading the images.

```
 public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = ImageLoadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    String url, userId;
    String[] items;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, String userId, String[] items) {
        this.url = url;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.items = items;
    }

    private String getImageUrlFromJson(String imageJson) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject imageJsonOutput = new JSONObject(imageJson);
        imageJsonUrl = imageJsonOutput.getString("imageUrl");
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, imageJsonUrl);
        return imageJsonUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String imageJson = null;
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url + userId);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (input == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                //jsonStr = null;
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            imageJson = buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String imageUrl = getImageUrlFromJson(imageJson);
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            addBitmapToMemoryCache(userId, bmp);
            return bmp;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bmp = result;
        item = new RowItem(bmp, item[0], item[1], item[2]);
        mDiscoverAdapter.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your reason for not using Picasso? It's possible to omit that library but you'll just have to replace much of what it does on your own.

Comment: Universal Image Loader have inbuilt option for chaching. It is a good library.

Comment: thought i would have to change my code more to be able to use picasso than i have to. thank you though for your help, i'm gonna use it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel by not using an existing image loading library. Have a look at some of the top libraries:

- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

If you are still determined to build it yourself. You will need to create a caching system to save/load from memory/disk as needed.  Also be careful about leaking views as this can get very tricky with image loading (esp a list or grid) with orientation change.

The official android documentation has a great tutorial on [Loading/Caching Images](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).  Go through that and have a look at the sample app that they provide to help you get started.